# Unified Background Across Multiple LoginViews

Tags: ios, swift

I have a login screen with multiple pages, I am just looking for an idea of what the best approach would be to slide between the different views, whilst maintaining the same background image.

I would like it to appear as if the background image is not changing but the appropriate view would slide in from the side.

Any ideas, or any suggestions on where to look would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way is to add the imageView to the UIWindow and every Controller should be with background color clear ;)

Comment: I have tried this method, cannot seem to get it to work. Any suggestion on how this is done? I was creating an image view and adding that as a subview to 'window'. Where should this be done? In AppDelegate, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions?

Comment: Can you add some code to see? Maybe the error is in your code.

Comment: In didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, let image = UIImage(named: "example.png") let imageView = UIImageView(image : image) window?.addSubview(imageView)

Comment: Just seem to get the clear background, assuming that the background image has not been added correctly.